# whether hibernate hit twice in data base if same service is used by 2 users simultaneously?

Tags: database, hibernate

i am using mvc pattern. and i am using Hibernate as my ORM tool. So what hibernate will do   if multiple users hit a service simultaneously . Whether it will go for that many DB hit or it will hit only once ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be one database hit per user request. If you configure second level cache, it will be one time per application.

Within one user request you can configure to cache the query, so the hibernate will cache the date within the session and return you data from it if you try to invoke the same query again.

Comment: So you are saying each user request it will go for database hit even though same service is calling by number of users ?. Then what is the use of persistence  property ?. As per my understanding hibernate will give result from the same persistence object until or unless an insertion will happen on that particular table. is that right ?

Comment: @arjun could you please let me know what persistent property you are mentioning about. Give me a link please

Comment: from my understandings. reach pojo classes will have 2 state . ie transient , persistent.(other states are also there). So hibernate will do all operation after making the pojo in a persistence state. eq: suppose we are deleting an object hibernate first execute a select query and take the object from database to persistent state. then it will execute deletion. after that commit will occur. Zeus i am not at all an expert in this things. i am still in a learning phase. if you think my understandings are wrong. pls correct me